# Visual Basic for Microsoft Access Training

Tags: ms-access

I am currently trying to learn how to create, run, and manage a Database for a company that deals with Chemicals.

My question is simple. Is there a website or a very good read that can help me understand and learn VBA or Visual Basic?

Comment: If you will not be managing this yourself, SQL Express may not be the best bet unless you know who it will be managed by. There may be costs involved that could be avoided with Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest better go for some better database technology. Use SQL server 2008; and since even with VBA you need to learn from scratch, why not learn SQL. The technology is far better and manageable than access and VBA

Comment: I am actually learning PHP, SQL, and VBA all at once, but I will look into the SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Ummm, stating that SQL Server Express is far better and more managable than VBA is like comparing apples and fishes.

Comment: agree with Tony Toews. This was a terrible answer. Using SQL Server 2008 with Sever's Query Language is a good idea. The reality of it is that you still need some type of "front end" GUI development tool/language. You should probably use either Access/VBA or Visual Basic .Net for the GUI. Regardless of what you use, you'll need to learn at least some of the SQL language (which confusingly is not unique to MS SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

The [Access developers handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782123716) (Litwin and Getz) is by far the best reference. **BUT**, are you sure you want to be developing your application in Access? Why not use [SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx)?

[SQL Server 2008 Express How-To-Guide Series](http://www.msdev.com/directory/SeriesDescription.aspx?CourseId=124)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, I will definitely look into SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: Good suggestion about the Developers Handbook but SQL Server Express has added layers of complexity which include require IT staff to install it.

Comment: Hi Tony. That's true (although you can install locally to develop against), and there is a deployment 'story'. I think you also need to factor in how long before Access goes the way of FoxPro...

Comment: Another answer that ignores one of the bigger questions. What should the frontend application be developed in?

Comment: With all the resources MS has put into Access with the last two versions, I'm pretty sure it's not "going the way of FoxPro" any time soon. If it did, then MS would have no desktop database application for inclusion in its office suite. Fears of the demise of Access are really overblown, in my opinion. Tossing out Access would be an action that would reflect huge changes and they'd never do it unless they had something comparable to replace it. Given that there isn't any competitor to Access except FileMaker Pro, I can't really imagine that MS would do that.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: you make a good point. I must confess I do miss the ease with which front-end applications can be created in MS Access, plus you can still have a SQL Server backend.

Comment: @HK1: the question doesn't explicitly ask what to develop a front-end application in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't bite off more than you can chew. And by that, I mean start with plain old Access and use it for storing your data. After you've learned how to do that, and are comfortable with designing a data schema and using SQL, you can upsize the back end to SQL Server Express.

But I wouldn't do that unless there's a compelling reason to do so. You don't say enough about the application for anyone to judge whether there's a good reason for that or not.